# unauthorized access to dovecot services

Tags: debian, postfix, spam-prevention, dovecot, spoofing

Recently i was enable mail-relay to 3rd party tool, suddenly i found 1000 of emails are going as a spam everyday to unknown users i disable the mail-relay ,but still we facing some one login our dovecot and start sending spam email through our postfix server how can prevent login them and sent email

check attach pic advice me on this

thanks  [postfix/smtpd warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUIYp.png)

[dovecot authentication warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhoWR.png)
attached the Dovecot login access there users are not available how to

Comment: Did the mail relay allow sending mails without authentication?

Comment: yes , its login through dovecot tty for smtp and start get send email to others, really i dont know how they access my mailbox .finally i block them in firewall

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like there are any successful authentications.
Your logs clearly show that the authentication has failed, meaning no valid user credentials have been supplied.

This is quite normal with the high number of bots out there.